# Celery Worker Stops Execution and Continuously Prints the Same Logs

Tags: python, docker, celery

I have an application that uses a Celery worker to run some data pipelines. Requests that are made to my service are handled by a container running a Flask app and then delegated to the Celery worker to run the pipeline.

One particular pipeline I have parses an XML file and stores the data in a database. When I try loading a relatively small file this works fine without any problem, however, I need to be able to parse large files (>9GB). When I try doing this though, the pipeline starts its execution, but comes to a halt at one point and keeps printing the logs given below,

```
[2021-10-26 17:50:10,824: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Synchronizing schedule...
[2021-10-26 17:50:10,826: DEBUG/Beat] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

What exactly has happened here? I have no reason to believe that any error has taken place, because I do not see any logs to this affect. How can I fix this problem?

I am using Redis as my task queue. My Celery worker is built from a base Python image and given below is the command I run at the end through my Dockerfile,

```
CMD [ "celery", "-A", "worker.celery", "worker", "--loglevel=debug", "--concurrency=10", "-P", "solo", "-n", "%h", "-B" ]
```

Comment: I guess that your container failed due to OOM (out of memory). Did you try to run `docker stats` to see memory usage vs. limit?

Comment: Yes, from what we could see resource utilization was not an issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate how did you check this? Where are you running the container? (machine spec)